# using the path function to change the search path

Tags: matlab

So I am trying to save a new search path.

I am trying to follow this example from Mathworks [Mathworks example](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/path.html)

My code is below. mypath is a 120 x 1 cell

```
path('mypath')
```

However when I run the code a pop up window says "Error using eval Underfined function 'workspacefunc' for input arguments of type 'struct'

When I try to check the path using the line below I get told the 'path may be bad'

```
checkPath = path;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version they provide works with an array of strings, not a cell of strings. Hence, this should work:

```
mypath = char(mypath);
path('mypath');
```

Comment: I took the line "path('newpath') changes the search path to newpath, where newpath is a string array of folders" to mean that I could pass all paths in one go? Also I want to remove the existing paths then add my paths

Comment: @mHelpMe Indeed. I had misread the documentation. I have updated the answer with another potential problem. Does that solve the issue for you?

Comment: sadly not. Still getting path may be bad. when I run path('mypath') it does throw out a warning "Name is nonexistent or not a directory: mypath In path at 34

Comment: The directories I'm trying to add already exist in my search path however I thought by using the path('mypath') that would over write the current pathdef file